# Rails rspec unexpected tIDENTIFIER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm going through the RoR tutorial, ran into the following error and can't seem to figure it out. I copied the sample code exactly but my rspec test still won't run (console won't even create a new User)

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Error:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/rails_projects/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec spec/
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/user/Ruby/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Here's my rspec test:
require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a"* 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is not valid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. 
                    foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.com A_US-ER@f.b.org first.last@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address|
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

And here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This line has a typo:

```
    @user.email = valid_address|
```

There's a trailing | that shouldn't be there